# Do not terminate WSL after it has executed command

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a batch script which in turn loads up WSL and runs a shell script. It looks a little like this:

```
  rem other stuff is done before this...
  wsl --exec script.sh
  print "oops you have exited wsl"
```

I need WSL to stay open after that shell script has run. The obvious answer is to run the script in .bashrc or /etc/profile but this is not appropriate because script.sh needs to change directory, and the change in directory is lost when running inside of .bashrc or /etc/profile once the script ends.

Do you have any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: You can call the script from a start-up file, but you need to invoke it with `source` (or `.`) to avoid starting a subshell, as in `. script.sh`.

Comment: Or just pause the bash script, add `read -p "Press enter to continue"`.

Comment: It turns out that it my script needed modifying, not my method of invoking it. Thanks for the advice!